# Image control not refreshed in windows phone app

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a list of images in my app, which are all inside a list box, I am giving the source as a URL.

Everything working fine, am able to show the image from the URL I have given.

When I change a image, and reload my `ListBox` that change is not reflecting on that image, it shows the old image not the new one.

I am sure, after image change I bind the new image URL to the source, but it shows the old image, I am not able to find why is this happening, here my code

```
  <ListBox Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,81,0,0" Name="wishListListBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480" Visibility="Visible">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

                    <Image ImageFailed="wishlistImage_ImageFailed_1" x:Name="wishlistImage" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="164" Margin="12,54,0,88" Stretch="Fill">
                        <Image.Source>
                            <BitmapImage CreateOptions="DelayCreation,IgnoreImageCache" UriSource="{Binding thumb_image}" />
                        </Image.Source>
                    </Image>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

    </ListBox>
```

here is my class from which i set itemsource for my image

```
[DataContract]
public class WishListResponse : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

 [DataMember]
 public List<string> thumb_images { get; set; }

 public string thumb_image
    {
        get
        {
            if (thumb_images.Count != 0)
                return thumb_images[0];
            else
                return "";
        }
        set
        {
            thumb_images[0] = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(thumb_images[0]);
        }
    }
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
 }
```

and in my main page i bind the item source like this

```
 public static List<WishListResponse> wishlistList = new List<WishListResponse>();

 wishListListBox.ItemsSource = wishlistList.ToArray();
```

Can anybody help me to refresh my image control.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you show the definition of the list and the code/property where you are assigning it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried very simple solution in this issue, and it works for me,

i just changed the image link every time when i need to refresh the image,
that means i just append the current time with the image url.

That works fine for me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Okay thank you for your update :-)

First to your original question.. ;-) If you replace your `List` to an `ObservableCollection` it will automatically update the UI when you change an entry of the list.

```
 public ObservableCollection<string> ThumbImages { get; set; }
```

Now if you ever set ThumbImages new i.e. assign a new object to it, you will have to set the DataContext again to the new reference, for example:

```
ThumbImages = new ObservableCollection<string>(wishListResponse.thumb_images);
DataContext = ThumbImages;
```

Now usually you set the datacontext to the model of the view, which in your case is a list of string. You can set the datacontext like this in your code behind:

```
DataContext = ThumbImages;
```

Then you can reference the datacontext with the default binding:

```
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">...</ListBox>
```

So you will no longer need to create a special property on your WishListResponse and set the ItemTemplate again to the Element i.e. in this context again the default binding:

```
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,81,0,0" Name="wishListListBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480" Visibility="Visible">

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

                    <Image ImageFailed="wishlistImage_ImageFailed_1" x:Name="wishlistImage" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="164" Margin="12,54,0,88" Stretch="Fill">
                        <Image.Source>
                            <BitmapImage CreateOptions="DelayCreation,IgnoreImageCache" UriSource="{Binding}" />
                        </Image.Source>
                    </Image>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

    </ListBox>
```

HTH

Comment: Hi thank you for your support, can you please tell me more about this solution, where i need to implement this INotifyChange, and how to link my ListBox refresh , with this event

Comment: @Noorul could you please provide a bit more code? I.e. where do you bind the datacontext? If you bind a custom object (one you created) to it. That class would have to inherit INotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the change in code is not notified to the xaml so you will have to inherit the the class from INotifyChange and then make a property change event ... like

```
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
```

then in the set of the property of the list after

```
 listname = value;
OnPropertyChanged("listname");
```

i hope this might help you ....

Comment: Hi thank you for your support, can you please tell me more about this solution, where i need to implement this INotifyChange, and how to link my ListBox refresh , with this event.

Comment: just inherit your class with INotifyPropertyChange and raise the the event as shown in answer.. and then do changes in your list they will be reflected on screen ...

Comment: i think you must show some code so that we might be able to help you properly

Comment: do one thing instead of inheriting WishListResponse  class with onproperty change inherit mainpage with and call the onproperchanged method on the like this 

private static List<WishListResponse> _wishlistList;
public static List<WishListResponse> wishlistList
{
get
{
return _wishlistList ;
}
set
{
_wishlistList  = value;
OnPropertyChanged("wishlistList ");
}
}

then wishlistList = new List<WishListResponse>();
wishListListBox.ItemsSource = wishlistList;

Answer (score 0):

i think the reason is you model don't implements INotifyPropertyChanged , so you property has changed ,but can't notify the image binding property,    to solve this

one is implements INotifyPropertyChanged ;

another you can do like this

```
wishListListBox.ItemsSource =null;
wishListListBox.ItemsSource = itemsSource;
```

it also  make your listbox show the new items

but it has problem  when  the itemsSource changed you must do like this ........

wish this can help you